# How could Germans be using an animated presentation to depict their attack plan?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

In episode 10 of season 2, it is shown that a German military official is giving walkthrough of the  imminent attack on the Japanese with a presentation, where we could clearly see that that is an animated simulation of 3 phases of their attack.

Wouldn't the computer technology be very primitive at that time?

Also in episode 9, it was shown that Japanese General Onoda was still using some models on a table to convey their attack strategy.

Could it be a pure negligence or are there any other explanations for that?

Following picture is for refernce :

[image]

Comment: Well we don't **know** it's computer generated...although it seems likely. Animated movies were around before the war...oh, and this is a fantasy/science fiction show.

Comment: Now you have removed 'computer' from Animated; your question makes even less sense. Animation was prevalent by the mid 40's, and the earliest animated films were introduced at the turn of the century.

Answer (score 2):

As Paulie_D had mentioned in the comments, It's hard to really tell, if they are computer generated animated images, but animation existed prior to World War II with iconic films such as Walt Disney's *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs*, released in 1937 AND the first [Computer animated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computer_animation_in_film_and_television) film (only 49 seconds long) called *Rendering of a Planned Highway* existed in 1960 via BESK Computer. The series primarily takes place starting in the year 1962...

However, the real point of interest here is that *The Man in the High Castle* takes place in an **alternate parallel universe**, where the Nazis won the war and where they and the Imperial Japanese occupy all major continents.

The series is very careful not to overdo its science-fiction elements, keeping it grounded and making it still feel generally close to our own history, *but* there are hints at **alternate innovation and technological advancements** in some areas. One of the most noticeable are the German Super Sonic Passenger Jets, also referred to as "Rockets" featured briefly in season 1.

[image: Nazi passenger jet]

In the [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle) of the same name on which the TV series is loosely based, "Rockets" go between Berlin and San Francisco in just 45 minutes, but on the TV series the character Rudolph Wegener exclaims that it only took two hours! Both cases show significant advancement, but the books describe the Rockets having other advancements too.

In addition, as the mythology of the series slowly develops, viewers come to learn that,

> not only are there film reels showing alternate histories, including
>  **alternate futures**, but that they are all real and brought to this
>  reality/universe by **parallel universe time travellers**!

With that in mind, it's not a stretch to presume how some of the technology could be advanced by comparison!

It's true that technology of the computer generated images looks further along, than of what it should be, *if it were our timeline*, it's still hard to tell IMO, but it's also possible that it is slightly advanced, which is line with the reality *The Man in the High Castle* has been conveying.

Comment: And that [Mercedes 600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_600) isn't from the 1940's either.

Comment: @Snow the main alternate reality that the series primarily takes place in begins it's story in 1962. I don't recall how much time had passed between seasons 1 and 2, but it isn't out of sorts for Nichole to have that 1963-era car.

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that the OP was assuming a 1940's scenario based on the "primitive" animation theory.  Of course, 1960's era animation is a lot less primitive in nature.

Comment: No worries and I agree. I have edited my answer to try and better reflect that.